# How to copy object(s) to another layer

Tags: objects, layers

I am building a model for a game and have decided to copy part of it into a separate layer. How do I copy one or more objects to a different layer?

Comment: It's important to know whether you want to COPY the object or MOVE the object. Your question is a bit confusing. You asked how to COPY, then how to MOVE. Be sure you understand the difference between the two or you'll quickly find yourself confused by having more objects than you intended. The first answer correctly tells you how to COPY the object to a different layer, the second answer tells you how to MOVE the object to a different layer. Not meaning to be critical here, but using the correct terminology helps to clarify your question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To copy an object you have to be in *Object* mode, right click on the object that you want to copy and the press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it first.

The duplicate will be in grab mode so right click to get out of grab mode without changing its location.

The object will still be selected but if it isn't, you can look in the *Outliner* for it. It will have the original object name followed by a number indicating that is a duplicate such as `Object.001`.

You then press <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the layer move popup menu and click the button for the layer that you want to move it to or alternatively type the number corresponding to the layer.

Answer (score 9):

Select the objects that you want to move and press <kbd>M</kbd>, then select the layer you want to move them to. You can also have an object in several layers, for that after pressing <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select the layers.